# How to split "をしていたとされ" to correct words? I try to split to words and query in dictionary but get nothing result

Tags: meaning, words

I tried to split and query `をしていたとされ` in https://tangorin.com/ but get nothing result.

> 日本軍占領下の江蘇省で日本の特務機関ジェスフィールド76号に協力**をしていたとされ**
>   https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%9F%E6%B2%A2%E6%B0%91

Answer (score 4, accepted):

を -- particle to mark the object of a verb.

していた -- past tense progressive form of する.

と -- quotative particle.

され -- continuative form of される which is passive form of する.

Xに協力をしていたとされ -- said/thought/considered to have been cooperating with X and ...

Comment: Thank you. Are some links(such as dictionarys or Japanese learn websites or other) can prove your answer? pretty please.